# AWS IoT rule which will invoke, whenever we will publish (or perform any IoT action) irrespective of the topic names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am testing AWS IoT rule to republish for the IoT topic with an AWS IOT rule actions. My mqtt clients are publishing in different topics: device A publish data into topicA, device B publish data into topicsB.

So in AWS IoT console, I defined a SQL rule selecting all devices coming from the topic as '#'. In this case, I'm not able to invoke rule if 
one of mttq client is publishing for the topic 'topicA' or 'topicB'.

I have written my rule by following these steps:

1.My query string is

```
SELECT * FROM '#'
```

2.My action is Republish messages to an AWS IoT topic. This action will republish the message to another AWS IoT topic given below:

```
topicsC
```

What is the right way to invoke a rule which is in my case if someone published for any topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a republish rule where the input topic filter includes the output topic. e.g. if you can't have `SELECT * FROM #` and publish to a topic called `topicsC` because `topicsC` is included in `#`. If you could the rule would invoke itself.

You should add a `/` to create a namespace in your topics.

You could have devices A and B publish to `device/A` and `device/B` respectively. Then you can have a republish rule `SELECT * FROM 'device/#` which republishes to a different topic, `alldata`.